# PHP OPcache optimization levels - what are they?

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, opcache

There is an [opcache.optimization_level](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.optimization-level) php.ini directive. It is a bitmask a defaults to `0xffffffff` - so by default OPcache does all the optimizations.

What kind of optimizations does OPcache do? What passes on bytecode are done?

Follow-up question: is there a code pattern that OPcache can optimise very well? For example, HHVM can skip execution of files that contain only class/function declarations and it just fills class/function tables.

Comment: A somewhat incomplete doc is available here: https://phpinternals.net/categories/opcache

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The bits of `opcache.optimization_level` correspond to:

- bit 0 - pass 1:

  - [CSE](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) - constants subexpressions elimination
  - Sequences of ADD_CHAR/ADD_STRING optimization
  - convert CAST(IS_BOOL,x) into BOOL(x)
  - convert [INTI_FCALL_BY_NAME](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.init-fcall-by-name.php) + [DO_FCALL_BY_NAME](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.do-fcall-by-name.php) into [DO_FCALL](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.do-fcall.php)
- bit 1 - pass 2:

  - Convert constant operands to expected types
  - Convert conditional [JMP](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.jmp.php) with constant operands
  - Optimize static [BRK](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.brk.php) and [CONT](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.cont.php)
- bit 2 - pass 3:

  - Convert $a = $a + expr into $a += expr
  - Convert $a++ into ++$a
  - Optimize series of [JMP](http://php.net/manual/internals2.opcodes.jmp.php)s
- bit 3 - pass 4:

  - PRINT and ECHO optimization - [removed](https://github.com/zend-dev/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/73)
- bit 4 - pass 5:

  - block optimization (the most expensive optimization pass which perform many different optimization patterns based on CFG - [control flow graph](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph))
- bit 8 - pass 9:

  - register [allocation](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) (allows re-usage of temporary variables)
- bit 9 - pass 10:

  - remove NOPs

I've looked around to see if I can find anything on any code patterns that it handles better than others, but I haven't had any luck.

Information from https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/blob/master/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.c and https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032?ocp.php

Comment: There are more passes now. https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%40master/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.h

Comment: Link from Thomas is dead. Here is the relevant file in the github repo:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/opcache/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.h

Comment: Your link is also dead. ;) https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5b01c4863fe9e4bc2702b2bbf66d292d23001a18/Zend/Optimizer/zend_optimizer.h